# CSS how to change color of circular progress bar as it grows? (Only CSS)

Tags: css

I have got this code from Web, pure CSS that allows me to display a growProgressBar in any webpage. What I want to achieve is to change the color based on different html style values.

From 0 to 20: --fg: red; --bg: pink;

From 20 to 40: --fg: orange; --bg: peachpuff;

From 40 to 60: --fg: yellow; --bg: lightyellow;

From 60 to 80: --fg: royalblue; --bg: lightblue;

From 80 to 100: --fg: green; --bg: lightgreen;

There's no need to have it changing the color as it grows, at least use the right one based on the given value.

This is the CSS and HTML Code:

```css
@keyframes growProgressBar {
            0%,
            33% {
                --pgPercentage: 0;
            }
            100% {
                --pgPercentage: var(--value);
            }
        }
        @property --pgPercentage {
            syntax: '<number>';
            inherits: false;
            initial-value: 0;
        }
        div[role="progressbar"] {
            --size: 12rem;
            --fg: green;
            --bg: lightgreen;
            --pgPercentage: var(--value);
            animation: growProgressBar 3s 1 forwards;
            width: var(--size);
            height: var(--size);
            border-radius: 50%;
            display: grid;
            place-items: center;
            background:
                radial-gradient(closest-side, white 80%, transparent 0 99.9%, white 0),
                conic-gradient(var(--fg) calc(var(--pgPercentage) * 1%), var(--bg) 0);
            font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: calc(var(--size) / 5);
            color: var(--fg);
        }
        div[role="progressbar"]::before {
            counter-reset: percentage var(--value);
            content: counter(percentage) '%';
        }
```

```html
<div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="--value:90"></div>
```

Comment: Some code somewhere is setting that HTML style attribute value to --value: 90; Is there any reason that code can't also set --fg and --bg?

Comment: Just a sidenote here...There's a couple of things in this code that are not supported in various browsers.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@property#browser_compatibility , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-reset#browser_compatibility

Answer (score 1):

I would consider a different idea.

Here is the portion of the code that you need to update

```css
background:
  /* if p > 40% blue */
  linear-gradient(blue 0 0) 0/calc((var(--pgPercentage) - 40)*1px) 100%,
  /* else if p > 20 red */
  linear-gradient(red  0 0) 0/calc((var(--pgPercentage) - 20)*1px) 100%,
  /* else green */
  green;
```

I only used 3 colors to demonstrate the technique but you can have as many color as you want.

```css
@keyframes growProgressBar {
  0%,
  33% {
    --pgPercentage: 0;
  }
  100% {
    --pgPercentage: var(--value);
  }
}

@property --pgPercentage {
  syntax: '<number>';
  inherits: true;
  initial-value: 0;
}

div[role="progressbar"] {
  --size: 2rem;
  --fg: green;
  --bg: lightgreen;
  --pgPercentage: var(--value);
  animation: growProgressBar 3s 1 forwards;
  width: 12rem;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: grid;
  background: radial-gradient(farthest-side, #0000 calc(100% - var(--size)),var(--bg) 0);
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: calc(var(--size) );
  color: var(--fg);
}

div[role="progressbar"]::after {
  content:"";
  grid-area: 1/1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: var(--size);
  background:
    /* if p > 40% blue */
    linear-gradient(blue 0 0) 0/calc((var(--pgPercentage) - 40)*1px) 100%,
    /* else if p > 20 red */
    linear-gradient(red  0 0) 0/calc((var(--pgPercentage) - 20)*1px) 100%,
    /* else green */
    green;
  --_m: 
    conic-gradient(#000 calc(var(--pgPercentage) * 1%), #0000 0),
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0) content-box;
  -webkit-mask: var(--_m);
          mask: var(--_m);
  -webkit-mask-composite: source-out;
          mask-composite: subtract;
}

div[role="progressbar"]::before {
  counter-reset: percentage var(--value);
  content: counter(percentage) '%';
  grid-area: 1/1;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="--value:90"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @Temani, that's great approach, worked good here, thanks!. just suggested an edit for better coloring, please consider it.

Comment: Hello again @Temani, just tested solution in Safari, but the background is not changing based on your approach. Just tried with a number below 20 and the background color is not showing up.

Comment: @FedericoLoyato unfortunately, it won't work on Safari and I didn't find a fix for this.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally taken parts of the responses, to build an alternative with a new conic-gradient that works cross browser.

Anyway animation only works in Chrome currently. Is there any way to make the animations working in Firefox and Safari as well?

```css
        @keyframes growProgressBar {

            0%,
            33% {
                --pgPercentage: 0;
            }

            100% {
                --pgPercentage: var(--value);
            }
        }

        @property --pgPercentage {
            syntax: '<number>';
            inherits: true;
            initial-value: 0;
        }

        div[role="progressbar"] {
            --size: 1.2rem;
            --fg: Black;
            --bg: WhiteSmoke;
            --pgPercentage: var(--value);
            animation: growProgressBar 3s 1 forwards;
            width: 12rem;
            aspect-ratio: 1;
            border-radius: 50%;
            display: grid;
            background: radial-gradient(farthest-side, #0000 calc(100% - var(--size)), var(--bg) 0);
            font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: calc(var(--size));
            color: var(--fg);
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(5%, 0%);
        }
        
        
        div[role="progressbar"]:hover {    
            --size: 1.2rem;
            font-weight: bold;
  }
        div[role="progressbar"]::after {
            content: "";
            grid-area: 1/1;
            border-radius: 50%;
            padding: var(--size);
            background:
                conic-gradient(red, orange, yellow, green);
            --_m:
                conic-gradient(#000 calc(var(--pgPercentage) * 1%), #0000 0),
                linear-gradient(#000 0 0) content-box;
            -webkit-mask: var(--_m);
            mask: var(--_m);
            -webkit-mask-composite: source-out;
            mask-composite: subtract;
        }

        div[role="progressbar"]::before {
            counter-reset: percentage var(--value);
            content: counter(percentage) '%';
            grid-area: 1/1;
            margin: auto;
        }
```

```html
<div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="--value:45;float: left;"></div>
<div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="--value:75;float: left;"></div>
<div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="--value:90"></div>
```